# running data given by a dictionary (javascript)

Tags: javascript

How do I run the data in the dictionary?

input:

```
const items = {
  34: ["a", "t"],
  43: ["d", "u"],
};
```

output:

```
run({34: "a"}),
run({34: "t"}),
run({43: "d"}),
run({43: "u"}),
```

Tried this:

```
[{ [Object.keys(items)[0]]: items[Object.keys(items)[0]] }]
```

but the output isn't quite what I wanted.

Comment: What _exactly_ do you mean by _"output"_? Are you wanting to call the `run()` function with those arguments or is this some sort of formatted string?

Comment: I rolled back edit 3 to edit 2 because it could have changed the meaning of the OP, we're awaiting the response to Phil's question.

Comment: You keep changing your accepted answer vote but not responding to the question above. Please [edit] your question for clarity or at least respond in the comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Iterate the entries then iterate the value array.
2. Construct an object from the entry key and the array value and pass it to `run()`

```js
const items = {
  34: ["a", "t"],
  43: ["d", "u"],
};

// for demonstration purposes
const run = (arg) => console.log("run:", JSON.stringify(arg));

Object.entries(items).forEach(([ key, arr ]) => {
  arr.forEach((val) => {
    run({ [key]: val });
  });
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can go over all of the entries, then make an object for each of the values inside of that data array. `.flatMap` will perform `.map` then `.flat` to make it a single depth array, but [`.flatMap` is more efficient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) than calling them separately.

```js
const items = {
  34: ["a", "t"],
  43: ["d", "u"],
};

const toRun = Object.entries(items).flatMap(
  ([key, values]) => values.map((value) => ({[key]: value}))
);

console.log(toRun);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Then when you're ready to call the function, you can either do a `.forEach` over `toRun`, or you can change the internal to `run({[key]: value})` if you want it immediately (change `.flatMap` and `.map` to `.forEach` if you don't care about the output of them)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want (Split the object into entries and build new objects from the list values):

```js
const items = { 34: ["a", "t"], 43: ["d", "u"], };
const result = Object.entries(items).flatMap(([id, chars]) => chars.map(char => ({[id]: char}))) 
console.log(result)
```